# Can someone explain me what do these operators mean in C#?

Tags: c#

Here are operators I need help with:

% (for example A%B)

!= (a%b != 0)

&(&&)

I'm very new to C# , so please try to explain me as simple as possible.

Comment: [C# Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx). Literally just typed that into Google. Hard to see why you couldn't have done the same.

Comment: I did, but I found something too complicated for me to understand.

Comment: `%` stands for remainder, so `A % B != 0` means *B doesn't divide A*. E.g.`A % 2 != 0` equals to *A is odd*

Comment: It is going to be very difficult to learn how to program in C# by asking one question at a time. I suggest purchasing a book on the language. Check Amazon to see what's hot.

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[% Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

> The % operator computes the remainder after dividing its first operand
>   by its second. All numeric types have predefined remainder operators.
>
> User-defined types can overload the % operator (see operator). When a
>   binary operator is overloaded, the corresponding assignment operator,
>   if any, is also implicitly overloaded.

[!= Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz250sf.aspx)

> The inequality operator (!=) returns false if its operands are equal,
>   true otherwise. Inequality operators are predefined for all types,
>   including string and object. User-defined types can overload the !=
>   operator.
>
> For predefined value types, the inequality operator (!=) returns true
>   if the values of its operands are different, false otherwise. For
>   reference types other than string, != returns true if its two operands
>   refer to different objects. For the string type, != compares the
>   values of the strings.
>
> User-defined value types can overload the != operator. So can
>   user-defined reference types, although by default != behaves as
>   described above for both predefined and user-defined reference types.
>   If != is overloaded, == must also be overloaded. Operations on
>   integral types are generally allowed on enumeration.

[& Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx)

> The & operator can function as either a unary or a binary operator.
>
> The unary & operator returns the address of its operand (requires
>   unsafe context).
>
> Binary & operators are predefined for the integral types and bool. For
>   integral types, & computes the logical bitwise AND of its operands.
>   For bool operands, & computes the logical AND of its operands; that
>   is, the result is true if and only if both its operands are true.
>
> The & operator evaluates both operators regardless of the first one's
>   value.

[&& Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx)

> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool
>   operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary.